# Accesos a usuarios

Tags: php, javascript, html, login

En mi base de datos tengo la siguiente tabla con columnas y registros..

Tabla `users`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer y no he tenido éxito es que por medio de un inicio de sesión compruebe obviamente su `id_user` y su `password_user` y dependiendo si es, `admin`, `receipt` o `output` mostrara diferentes paginas.

Con la siguiente estructura estoy consultando los `3` datos siempre y cuando `password_user` y `id_user` existan en la tabla

archivo `user.php`

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET')
{
  if(isset($_GET['id_user']) && isset($_GET['password_user']))
  {
    $id_user=$_GET["id_user"];
     $password_user=$_GET["password_user"];
     $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();

    $query = 'SELECT id_user,password_user,type_user from users where id_user = ? AND password_user= ?';
    $result=$connection->executeQuery($query, array($id_user,$password_user));

    if ($result>0)
    {
      $user = json_encode(array(
                'id_user' => $result[0][0],
                'password_user' => $result[0][1],
                'type_user' => $result[0][2]
              ));
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'user' => json_decode($user)
        ));
    }//if
    else
    {
      echo json_encode(array(
        'status' => 1,
        'errorMessage' => 'user not found'
        ));
    }//else
  }
} //CIERRA IF
```

Al poner los parámetros obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "user": {
        "id_user": "56012",
        "password_user": "123",
        "type_user": "admin"
    }
}
```

En lo siguiente muestro el `html` y la function en js que hace la validación para dar el acceso a los archivos dependiendo el `type_user`

```js
function login(id_user,password_user)
{
 //debugger
 console.log('ENTRE A LOGIN');
 var id_user =document.getElementById("user").value;
 var password_user =document.getElementById("pass").value;
 console.log(id_user);
 console.log(password_user);

//validar que no esten en blanco
 if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
  $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
  $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
  document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
  document.location.href="#errorLogin";
 }
 //si no estan en blanco avanza al ajax.
 else{
 var fd = new FormData();
    var data =  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
     data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function(data){
     var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;
      console.log(tipo_usuario);
     console.log('ENTRE AJAX');
     if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
     {
      console.log('entre if');
      window.location.href='./article.html';
     }
     else if(tipo_usuario == "receipt")
     {
      window.location.href='./receipt.html';
     }
     else if(tipo_usuario == "output")
     {
      window.location.href='./output.html';
     }
     else
     {
      alert('usuario no existe');
      return false;
     }
    },
    }); //fin ajax
   }
 console.log(data);
//}
}
```

```html
  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="user" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" id="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <!-- etiqueta de no dejar espacios en blanco -->
                <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display: none" id="errorLogin">
                </div>
              <button class="btn btn-w-m btn-success" type="button" onclick="login()">LOGIN</button>
```

Como se puede ver estoy recibiendo en mi `function` los parámetros `id_user` y `password_user`, los parámetros los recibe eso lo compruebo con el console, después valido si no están los campos en blancos, lo cual funciona bien, al ser falso entra al `AJAX` y necesito identificar el type_user es decir si es admin, le dará acceso al archivo `article.html` si es `receipt` al archivo `receipt.html` etc.

Con la siguiente linea trato de identificar el type_user que se hace por medio de la consulta  `var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;`

Al probarlo en la interfaz me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type_user' of undefined
>   En esta linea

```
var tipo_usuario = data.user.type_user;
```

Entonces no se como hacer esa parte, ya que no lo estoy recibiendo como parámetro, y por ende no avanza mas allá.

Al imprimir solo el `data` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
responseText: "{"status":0,"user":{"id_user":"56012","password_user":"123","type_user":"admin"}}"
```

Comment: `success: function(data){` en esa sección corta todo y solo coloca `console.log(data)` y pega la información que se imprime

Comment: Podes imprimir `data` del succes para verificar que el JSON del echo esté bien estructurado

Comment: Ya lo he actualizado.

Comment: @Pato, he visto un error, en la parte del `else` donde colocas la `url` el parámetro de `password_user` te falta colocarle el símbolo **=**, así  `url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user="+password_user,` intenta modificando esto.

Comment: Efectivamente faltaba el =, pero sigue apareciendo que type_user es undefined :/ actualizare la pregunta, de como imprime el data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navegando por internet, encontre que debes parsear tu respuesta del servidor para poder leer tu json en JS, te dejo lo que tendrías que hacer

```js
function login(id_user,password_user)
{
    //debugger
    console.log('ENTRE A LOGIN');
    var id_user =document.getElementById("user").value;
    var password_user =document.getElementById("pass").value;
    console.log(id_user);
    console.log(password_user);

//validar que no esten en blanco
    if (id_user  === '' || password_user == '') {
        $("#id_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        $("#password_user").parent().addClass('has-error');
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("errorLogin").innerHTML = "No puedes dejar campos en blanco, completa la informacion.";
        document.location.href="#errorLogin";
    }
    //si no estan en blanco avanza al ajax.
    else{
    var fd = new FormData();
                var data =  $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "apis/user.php?id_user="+id_user+"&password_user"+password_user,//A que archivo enviara los parametros
                 data: fd,//Parametros que se enviaran
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function(data){
                 var jsonParse = JSON.parse(data);  // aquí es donde tienes que usar JSON.parse()
var tipo_usuario = jsonParse['user'].type_user;

                  console.log(tipo_usuario);
                 console.log('ENTRE AJAX');
                 if(tipo_usuario == "admin")
                 {
                     console.log('entre if');
                        window.location.href='./article.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "receipt")
                 {
                     window.location.href='./receipt.html';
                 }
                 else if(tipo_usuario == "output")
                 {
                     window.location.href='./output.html';
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     alert('usuario no existe');
                     return false;
                 }
                },
                }); //fin ajax
            }
    console.log(data);
//}
}
```

Espero sea de ayuda! :D

Comment: Funciona muy bien, :o ahorita tengo otro error, tratare de resolverlo, gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: @Pato, Cualquier duda aquí estamos, suerte! :)